# Spring authorization customize claims in token generator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

Today I'm using a custom grant type password, I've implemented token generation, but I can't place custom claims, such as authorities and role

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CustomPasswordGrantAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final String ERROR_URI = "https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-5.2";
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService;
    private final OAuth2TokenGenerator<? extends OAuth2Token> tokenGenerator;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        CustomPasswordGrantAuthenticationToken passwordGrantAuthentication =
                (CustomPasswordGrantAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken clientPrincipal = getAuthenticatedClientElseThrowInvalidClient(authentication);

        RegisteredClient registeredClient = clientPrincipal.getRegisteredClient();

        if (registeredClient == null) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_CLIENT);
        }

        // Ensure the client is configured to use this authorization grant type
        if (!registeredClient.getAuthorizationGrantTypes().contains(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.UNAUTHORIZED_CLIENT);
        }

        Authentication usernamePasswordAuthentication = getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(passwordGrantAuthentication);

        // Generate the access token
        DefaultOAuth2TokenContext.Builder tokenContextBuilder = DefaultOAuth2TokenContext.builder()
                .registeredClient(registeredClient)
                .principal(usernamePasswordAuthentication)
                .authorizationServerContext(AuthorizationServerContextHolder.getContext())
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
                .authorizationGrant(passwordGrantAuthentication);

//        final var account = (AccountDetails) userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername("teste@teste.com");
//
//        Map<String, Object> customClaims = new HashMap<>();
//        customClaims.put("role", account.getRole());
//        customClaims.put("authorities", account.getAuthorities());

        OAuth2TokenContext tokenContext = tokenContextBuilder.tokenType(OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN).build();
        OAuth2Token generatedAccessToken = this.tokenGenerator.generate(tokenContext);
        if (generatedAccessToken == null) {
            OAuth2Error error = new OAuth2Error(OAuth2ErrorCodes.SERVER_ERROR,
                    "The token generator failed to generate the access token.", ERROR_URI);
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(error);
        }

        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = new OAuth2AccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken.TokenType.BEARER,
                generatedAccessToken.getTokenValue(), generatedAccessToken.getIssuedAt(),
                generatedAccessToken.getExpiresAt(), null);

        // Initialize the OAuth2Authorization
        OAuth2Authorization.Builder authorizationBuilder = OAuth2Authorization.withRegisteredClient(registeredClient)
                .principalName(usernamePasswordAuthentication.getName())
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
                .attribute(Principal.class.getName(), usernamePasswordAuthentication);
        if (generatedAccessToken instanceof ClaimAccessor) {
            authorizationBuilder.token(accessToken, (metadata) ->
                    metadata.put(
                            OAuth2Authorization.Token.CLAIMS_METADATA_NAME,
                            ((ClaimAccessor) generatedAccessToken).getClaims()));
        } else {
            authorizationBuilder.accessToken(accessToken);
        }

        OAuth2RefreshToken refreshToken = null;
        if (registeredClient.getAuthorizationGrantTypes().contains(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)) {
            tokenContext = tokenContextBuilder.tokenType(OAuth2TokenType.REFRESH_TOKEN).build();
            OAuth2Token generatedRefreshToken = this.tokenGenerator.generate(tokenContext);
            refreshToken = (OAuth2RefreshToken) generatedRefreshToken;
            authorizationBuilder.refreshToken(refreshToken);
        }

        OAuth2Authorization authorization = authorizationBuilder.build();

        // Save the OAuth2Authorization
        this.authorizationService.save(authorization);

        return new OAuth2AccessTokenAuthenticationToken(registeredClient, clientPrincipal, accessToken, refreshToken);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return CustomPasswordGrantAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

    private Authentication getUsernamePasswordAuthentication(CustomPasswordGrantAuthenticationToken resouceOwnerPasswordAuthentication) {

        Map<String, Object> additionalParameters = resouceOwnerPasswordAuthentication.getAdditionalParameters();

        String username = (String) additionalParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.USERNAME);
        String password = (String) additionalParameters.get(OAuth2ParameterNames.PASSWORD);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        log.info("got usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken=" + usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

        Authentication usernamePasswordAuthentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        return usernamePasswordAuthentication;
    }

    private OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken getAuthenticatedClientElseThrowInvalidClient(Authentication authentication) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken clientPrincipal = null;
        if (OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication.getPrincipal().getClass())) {
            clientPrincipal = (OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }

        if (clientPrincipal != null && clientPrincipal.isAuthenticated()) {
            return clientPrincipal;
        }

        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_CLIENT);
    }
}
```

My token generator and token customizer:

```java
@Bean
    public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> tokenCustomizer() {
        return context -> {
            Authentication principal = context.getPrincipal();

            if (context.getTokenType().equals(OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
                AccountDetails accountDetails = (AccountDetails) principal.getPrincipal();

                context.getClaims().claim("role", accountDetails.getRole())
                        .claim("authorities", accountDetails.getAuthorities()
                                .stream()
                                .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                                .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    OAuth2TokenGenerator<?> tokenGenerator(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        JwtGenerator jwtGenerator = new JwtGenerator(new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource));
        OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator accessTokenGenerator = new OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator();
        OAuth2RefreshTokenGenerator refreshTokenGenerator = new OAuth2RefreshTokenGenerator();
        return new DelegatingOAuth2TokenGenerator(
                jwtGenerator, accessTokenGenerator, refreshTokenGenerator);
    }
```

I hope that the final token has the claims authorities and role, since I am using this method to authenticate the user right after being created, in later logins the refresh token is used or the authorization code by the BFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your customizer token to the jwt generator. Here is an example of how your token generator configuration would look:

```java
@Bean
    OAuth2TokenGenerator<?> tokenGenerator(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        JwtGenerator jwtGenerator = new JwtGenerator(new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource));
        jwtGenerator.setJwtCustomizer(tokenCustomizer());
        OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator accessTokenGenerator = new OAuth2AccessTokenGenerator();
        OAuth2RefreshTokenGenerator refreshTokenGenerator = new OAuth2RefreshTokenGenerator();
        return new DelegatingOAuth2TokenGenerator(
                jwtGenerator, accessTokenGenerator, refreshTokenGenerator);
    }
```

In the documentation, it teaches how to customize the opaque token. Unfortunately, they added only on the opaque. Link: [Token customizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-token-customizer)